# MacBook Air issue: Keyboard and in built mic failing

Tags: keyboard, macbook-pro, microphone

The keys 9,o,l and . on the keyboard of my MacBook Air have stopped functioning all of a sudden. Instead of the intended characters, random characters from the *same row as the faulty keys* appear.

Also, the built-in mic is failing.

What could be the problem?

EDIT: The keyboard and mic problem started to appear after a defective screen panel was replaced a few days ago. I wonder how that could have caused the side effects I'm experiencing.

Comment: Sorry to hear that my suggestion really really didn't help! I typed the wrong folder name... I guess you have to either restore those files or do a little reinstall. Real sorry that happened, my fault big time.

Comment: Could you tell me the correct folder, if that could help? I'll try working remotely. :)

Comment: I meant not to include the `/System/Library/Keyboard Layouts` one (considered it, decided against it ,and forgot to remove it from the post). One to try could be `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.keyboardviewer.plist`, but that probably won't influence how the physical keyboard works.

Comment: @Nathan: I restored the Keyboard Layouts folder contents with the help of a [post](http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?p=10084219&postcount=16) at Mac Rumors. This could be a hardware problem; I'll have to check with the Apple Store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well to me that sounds like hardware failure.  I'd suggest that you just take it in to your local Apple Store or AASP; I don't see why they WOULDN'T replace the necessary parts (I don't know the MBA assembly well) if it's under warranty.

Comment: My MBA is not under warranty, but the keyboard problem coincided with the replacement of a defective screen panel. I wonder how the new panel could have affected the keyboard and mic.

Comment: As much as we like to think the Geniuses are really geniuses, they've done some pretty spotty jobs putting my Mac back together. I'd go in and say "Hey, this stopped working last time I came in here."